# How to sort by multiple columns for all values and not just duplicates - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `dataframe` for which I need to sort (by `ascending`) the values by two columns with the output being a "middle ground" of the two columns.

An example is shown bellow. When I use `sort_values` it sorts by the first columns and considers the second one only for duplicate values. I, however, need to get the row that have the combinaison of lower values for both columns (which is the 3rd one in the ouput bellow).

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({'file':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'rmse':[66,41,43,39,40,42], 'var':[44,177,201,321,349,379]})
test.sort_values(by=['rmse', 'var'], ascending=[True, True])

Output :

    file    rmse    var
3   4       39      321  <--- First row given by `sort_values`
4   5       40      349
1   2       41      177  <--- Row that I need
5   6       42      379
2   3       43      201
0   1       66      44
```

I'm not sure how to phrase my question properly in English so please tell me if I need to make my question more clear.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you just trying to sort rows by a key function that adds two columns together?

Comment: you mean the sum of two columns? pr concatenation of strings?

Comment: @Jeremy What I need is the combinaison of both ```rmse``` and ```var``` columns to be the smallest possible. In the example show here the first rows has the smallest ```rmse``` value but the ```var``` one being quite high. What I'd need is to get the row ```12       41      177``` which is a "middle ground" with 41 and 177 being the smallest values for both columns.

Comment: you need to understand what you want to sort by because it’s clearly not clear to you

Comment: @adirabargil I just don't know how to express my question properly in english... I need an output that gives me the smallest values for both columns, not just for one.

Comment: @I.M. When you say 'combination' do you mean the sum? ie compare result of `rmse + var` for each row when sorting?

Comment: @Jeremy No it would be the set of both values. The first row has a ```rmse``` value that is the smallest but the ```var``` one is very high. The last row has the smallest ```var``` but with a high ```rmse```. What I need is the row with ```rmse```=41 and ```var```=177 since this row gives small values for both columns (even if they're not the smallest one possible).

Comment: you need to define what you mean by "small values for both columns". I can just easily say, `rmse=66, var=44` is the smallest.

Comment: @I.M. You need to determine a formula in terms of `rmse` and `var` which will allow you to compare two rows together and determine which should come first in that case. Computers will do what you tell them; if you want to sort by some arbitrary metric of 'smallest', you will need to define this metric algorithmically

Comment: @enke @Jeremy Defining what I need/want is what I am trying to do but I don't know how. I really need the ```rmse``` value to be as small as possible while have a ```var``` value that is not high.

Comment: *I really need the rmse value to be as small as possible while have a var value that is not high* How do you know `rmse` or `var` is small enough? Your rule is entirely arbitrary at this point. Computers can't eyeball a value as *small*. Without some sort of function that defines what *small* is, you can't get your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, let's use `rank`, `mean`, and `argsort`:

```
test.iloc[test[['var', 'rmse']].rank().mean(axis=1).argsort()]
```

Output:

```
   file  rmse  var
1     2    41  177
3     4    39  321
0     1    66   44
4     5    40  349
2     3    43  201
5     6    42  379
```

Details, rank the values in each column, then average the ranks for each row and sort the mean ranks to determine row order.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the methods of `df.sort.values` but instead of that you can try a for loop like this :

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'file':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'rmse':[66,41,43,39,40,42], 'var':[44,177,201,321,349,379]})

for i in test:
    test[i]=sorted(test[i])
    print(test)
```

Output :

```
      file  rmse  var
  0     1    39   44
  1     2    40  177
  2     3    41  201
  3     4    42  321
  4     5    43  349
  5     6    66  379
```